# Is it true that the amount of necessary binary digits for any given positive integer is ceil( log_2 n)?

Tags: c, math, time-complexity

Title pretty much says it. I can only guess but I have no proof that this holds. In Python `math.ceil(math.log(n) / math.log(2))`.

Context: I'm creating a intbyte-to-char*binary function which only displays the necessary digits (id est no trailing zeros), thus I would need to dynamically allocate memory for the char array. However I assume there exists an upper bound which I could use to determine the length statically.

**Edit**: It seems my approach was wrong. To check the amount of digits necessary, it is way faster just to divide the number by 2 successively until it is 0 and keep track of the amount of divisions.

Comment: The correct formula is: `floor(log2(number)) + 1`

Comment: @2501: Phew. You verify the lucky punt in my (amended) answer ;-)

Comment: @Bathsheba As you mentioned, it only works correctly with unlimited precision.

Comment: Indeed. Using `floor` and `ceil` with `log` is a recipe for disaster.

Comment: For sure, you need: `1 + floor(log2(n))` binary digits to represent `(n)`. e.g., consider `n = 1` ; your formula gives `ceil(log2(1))` which gives you `ceil(0)`, clearly not the logical answer.

Comment: I think`ceil(log2(number + 1))` probably works as well? It is of course the exact powers of 2 that are problematic

Comment: Yes, log is relatively expensive, though it is a basic mathematical operation and so preferable in some contexts.

Comment: Posting more about "I'm creating a intbyte-to-char*binary function" would garner answers that address that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The formula is almost correct but you'll be out by one digit for exact powers of 2. The formula

`1 + math.floor(math.log(n) / math.log(2))`

would, I think, work better. But I wouldn't dwell on that too much simply because I'd never rely on a computer to compute `math.floor(math.log(n) / math.log(2))` without the risk of the result being one less due to imprecision centred around floating point and the computation of a `log`: for the latter you're at the mercy of your chipset.

Testing the length by repeated integer division by 2 until zero is attained would be more robust, and possibly faster. `log` is not a cheap function computationally. You could even use the flashy bit fiddle `x & (x - 1)` (Google it).

Comment: `math.ceil(math.log2(64)) = 6`. However, it takes 7 bits to encode 64. Beware of limit cases.

Comment: Testing by division by 2 until zero is attained is actually way more fast and clever I guess. Didn't think about it.

Comment: @AdHominem: Yes it is surprisingly quick. AFAIK, even the most modern chipsets use a Newton-Raphson approach to evaluate `log`, with a table of stored values to act as starting points.

Answer (score 2):

You have a nice answer from @Bathsheba, for the second part of the question:

> I would need to dynamically allocate memory for the char array.
>   However I assume there exists an upper bound which I could use to
>   determine the length statically.

You can use `snprintf` (with `NULL` as buffer and `0` as maximum num of bytes) to count the number of characters / digits:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    size_t len = snprintf(NULL, 0, "%d", 1234) + 1;
    char str = malloc(len);

    snprintf(str, len, "%d", 1234);
    puts(str);
    free(str);
    return 0;
}
```

Another way (if you can use GNU extensions) is [asprintf](https://linux.die.net/man/3/asprintf):

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE

#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *str;

    asprintf(&str, "%d", 1234);
    puts(str);
    free(str);
    return 0;
}
```